# C# delete contents in a 247 different subfolders

Tags: c#, batch-file

i want to delete all Contents in a subfolders.

C:\Folder --> root Directory

A,B,C,D,.... --> subfolders (info: there are 247 subsfolders)

I have no idea how I can implement it, e.g. in c# or Batch file.

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: C# or batch. They are not quite the same.

Comment: Yes, i have Administrator permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to delete everything inside your root folder (all the subfolders and all the files in them, also files in root folder itself), then Yes `Direcotry.Delete('path', true)` is what you need.

But if you need to retain the sub folders (A,B,C,D) while still deleting all the files in them, then there is no Direct/BuiltIn way to do that, 
for that in general, you need to first get all the folder inside your root folder, then loop through them, then delete all the files inside them, leaving the subfolder empty.

Something like this method (call the method passing root path):

```
private void DeleteJustFilesFromFolder(string roootPath)
{
   DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(roootPath);

   //delete files from root
   foreach (FileInfo fi in d.GetFiles())
   {
     fi.Delete();
   }

   //get root subfolders
   foreach (DirectoryInfo di in d.GetDirectories())
   {
      DeleteJustFilesFromFolder(di.FullName);

    //kept commented, but if you prefer then can delete subfolder by this line
    //di.Delete(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With true for the second parameter(recursive) all subfolder gets deleted!

```
Directory.Delete("yourpath", true);
```

If you want to remove the Content of the Directories you could do something like this:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("yourpath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList().ForEach(f => File.Delete(f));
```

Answer (score 4):

In batch it is (also) easy:

```
rmdir /S "C:\Folder"
```

Comment: Hey, the script clean up the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

In c#

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, 
                   "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

or

```
try
{
Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);
}
catch(UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
{
}
```

Note: If you don't have permission to the sourceDirectory, this won't work (try catch will prevent app error in both cases)

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can do it with:

```
foreach(string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Folder"))
   Directory.Delete(directory, true);
```

You can also pass a searchpattern to `Directory.GetDirectories(...)`